# 4-way switch circuit with Leviton smart dimmers

Tags: electrical, dimmer-switch

Now that I've spent two consecutive days mapping out the 4-way circuit to add smart dimmers, I may have a layout that isn't compatible. I'm using [Leviton D26HD](https://www.leviton.com/en/docs/DI-000-D26HD-02A-W.pdf) as the main dimmer and two [DD00R companions](https://www.leviton.com/en/docs/DI-R00-DD00R-02A-W.pdf) as the extra two dimmers.

Am I correct that the 4-way in the middle is replaced by a companion and the D26HD goes on the load end?

[my circuit looks like this](https://www.do-it-yourself-help.com/images/4-way-switch-diagram.svg)

Is there any way two get neutral wires into the 4-way box and into the 3-way box labelled SW2?

---

There are the instructions included with the companions for 4-way installations. Oddly, this document isn't to be found on Leviton's web page. I'll get it scanned and posted for future reference.

---

This is not the wiring setup that I found, but there are detailed instructions on using one dimmer and two dimmer companions in an existing 4-way circuit. Again, this would be useful for Leviton to post this for general public looking into the details.

---

[image: page 1 of the full instructions with companion]
[image: page 2 of the full instructions with companion]

Comment: The answer yes, but the problem is doing it easy.  All you have to do is extend the neutral at the light to the switches, but I bet you are not using conduit.

Comment: That particular dimmer was a very safe choice. However, that diagram you linked is extremely unclear. Are you saying power comes into the light, and you have two spurs to switches?

Comment: @crip659 I was hoping to use the existing wiring and not to climb into the attic. The basement 3-way setup had neutral wires at the switches, so I was surprised that this was run differently.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine The line (black wire) definitely arrives at SW1, but the neutral from the same 4-wire does not. As above, this is going to require a trip to the attic.

Comment: Having to require neutral wire at switches is a recent(a few years) code update, before neutral was not required at switches, many switch loops only needed hot and switch hot wires(plus ground).

Comment: I wasn't expecting to need to pull new wires. We will re-define what each of the wires do.   I need to know where they go, i.e. where are the ends of each cable?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

### Those remotes won't work. You need wireless.

Switch to the DAWDC or DAWSC wireless remotes. These communicate via radio, but still mount in a normal switch box like a wired switch.

Now, how do you wire it?  I'm assuming the wiring is "Power to the lamp, one /3 spur to one 3-way switch, another /3 spur to the 4-way and other 3-way".

Install the smart switch "master" on the single 3-way spur.  It'll be simpler.

You don't need to Reassign the wires as follows:

- White = actual neutral
- Black = always-hot
- Red = switched-hot (Load)

In the switch box, you'll wire it in an extremely obvious manner - like to like colors.

Up in the lamp box, rewire the lamp considerably.  On the /3 cable to the 4-way and other 3-way, remove all wires and cap them off.

On the /3 cable to the switch you are using, you wire it exactly like a *single* switch when doing a post-2011 "switch loop".   So black to (supply) black, red to lamp, and white to neutral.

In fact, the Leviton D26HD could be installed in a post-2011 single switch loop, and then, "turned into a 3-way" using those wireless remotes.

### I *really* want to use wired remotes, though.

OK, then you will need to run a /4 cable on the "single 3-way" side.  Diagram this out:

- White - neutral from supply to lamp and all switches
- Black - always-hot from supply to all switches
- Red - Datacomm line among all switches
- Blue (or white-red marked blue) - switched-hot (Load) from switch 1 to lamp.

You will need to change all the wiring to match that.   Blue is the 4th wire in /4 cable.  You can also use /2/2 cable where the 4th wire is white w/ red stripe, but re-mark it to blue.  It is not legal to use a white wire as a hot, unless it is re-marked a color or black.

Answer (score 2):

The instructions you have posted of the switches you're using show that the DD00R is a suitable replacement for your old 4-way switch and the D26HD is suitable for replacing 3-way sitches. Leviton is a great brand.

As far as getting a neutral to those two locations, you'll need to replace the three wire NB with four wire NB from the light fixture to the 4-way switch and from the 4-way switch to the SW2 switch. You should check out some different type dimmers that do not require a neutral.